# Удаление ненужных элементов из динамически подгружаемого контента

Tags: javascript

А возможно через JS удалить например на ютубе все элементы, кроме первой строки с роликами? Тут суть именно в том, что по мере удаления, динамически будут подгружаться новые превьюшки видео. А задача удалить всё лишнее из динамически подгружаемого контента, чтоб снизить нагрузку.
Вот пример удаления обычных элементов, например если их более 3-х в списке: https://qna.habr.com/q/405031
А реально ли удалить как на примере с тем же ютубом?

Я бы в теории сделал что-то вроде content.remove(); А потом подгрузил первую полоску. Только вот не знаю реально ли это сделать и как?

Comment: реально MutationObserver

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, Армен!
MutationObserver отслеживает изменения DOM-структуры, а что это может дать? Вот например после элемента video[1], пойдёт загрузка таких же video[2],3 и прочих. Если бы была возможность запретить дополнять дом структуру после определенного элемента.
Можно как только появится video[1] остановить загрузку страницы, тогда вроде проблема решена. Хотя так возможно не загрузится то что идёт за динамическим контентом.
Я почитал про MutationObserver, но что-то нужных мне примеров с ней не нахожу, попробую завтра поискать.

Answer (score 0):

как пример. Но что касается запрета допалнения я не знаю если сайт твой то просто надо отфилтровать данные перед добавлением в дом но тут речь шла про youtube или я что то не так понял

```js
let c = document.querySelector('#a')
let div = document.createElement('div')
let div2 = document.createElement('div')
div.classList.add('m1')
div2.classList.add('m2')

let observer = new MutationObserver((e) => {
  let x = e[0].addedNodes[0]
  if(x){
    x.remove()
  }
});

observer.observe(c, {
  childList:true
});

setTimeout(() => {
  c.append(div)
},1000)

setTimeout(() => {
  c.append(div2)
},3000)
```

```css
div{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.m1{
    background-color: green;
}

.m2{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
  <div id="a">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый пример! Да я я именно о ютубе спрашивал. Вот так на ютубе удаляется 3-й элемент, превью видео с текстом:
`document.querySelector("ytd-rich-item-renderer:nth-child(3)").remove();`

Вот так должны вроде удалятся, новые подгружаемые превьюхи, но у меня что-то так не получается:
`let c = document.querySelector('#contents > ytd-rich-item-renderer');

let observer = new MutationObserver((e) => {
  let x = e[0].addedNodes[0]
  if(x){
    x.remove()
  }
});

observer.observe(c, {
  childList:true
});`

Comment: Не очень понял как здесь в комментариях грамотно код поставить, здесь энтеры вырезаются. Мне кажется, что так используя _.remove()_ все равно будут бесконечно удалятся подгруженные динамически элементы. Я пробовал без использования _MutationObserver_ и у меня так и получалось.